# Is it possible to align a 1 to 1 unity model for Hololens 2 of a building in reference to a QR code coordinates?

Tags: unity-game-engine, qr-code, hololens, mrtk

I'm relatively new to everything relating to programming, and currently in a project where my task is to align a unity model of a building in the physical world. I have done quite a bit of research and came across different things, Fiducial markers and Vuforia but they don't seem to address the task at hand. I've lastly stumbled upon the Qr code tracking article in Microsoft website and it sounds promising, yet I lack the knowledge to understand if my task is possible throughout this method. I do believe that maybe it is possible to extract GameObject positions and reference them to a QR code, I'm not so sure.
Thank you for taking the time in reading this

Comment: The short answer is "yes". You can align a model with a QR code.
The long answer is that it is not as simple as you think it is. You will have to use some real-world reference points to link the position of your QR code to the position of your model. You need at least 4 such reference points to be able to align your model in 3D space. Once you have these 4 points, you can use the QR code to get your model's position in 3D space.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is there anything you could provide as a reading material for me to understand this more in depth ?

Comment: If you want to use a QR code to place a 3D model in the real world, you can use the Vuforia AR SDK.  The Vuforia AR SDK can be used with Unity3D. You can find more information about how to use the Vuforia AR SDK with Unity3D here: https://library.vuforia.com/getting-started/getting-started-vuforia-engine-unity

Comment: Your Assessment is correct. You can use the QR Project by Microsoft to align a 3D model in your Unity scene with a QR marker in the real world. The QR code has all the 3D spatial information, but on that scale you will have a problem with 1 marker in regards to rotational precision. Only  1 or 2 degrees deviation in tracking precision of the marker rotation will result after a few meters in a big discrepancy between real world and 3D model.